# Bonjour networked printer with Time Capsule in bridge mode

Tags: time-capsule, printing, bonjour

I have a 5th generation Airport Time Capsule as my primary router, and a 4th generation Airport Time Capsule in bridge mode, connected via cat5. When I connect my printer (a Brother HL-3040CN) to the 4th gen via USB, it's visible on the network and works fine. When I connect it by cat5 to one of the 4th gen's LAN ports, however, even though it seems to appear in the Bonjour list, from the 5th gen WiFi network I get "the printer is not responding". (This is after deleting it in the Printers and Scanners control panel and re-adding it as a new printer.)

Also suspicious is that when I try to ping the Bonjour address, `brn001ba94e93ac.local`, I get an IP address in the `192.168` range, even though the rest of my LAN is `10.0`.

So I guess my questions are:

1. is this a configuration that should work?
2. why is the printer showing up as a Bonjour device if I can't connect to it?
3. why is the Bonjour address mapped to an IP on a nonexistent subnet?

---

**Edited to add:** Ping and traceroute both fail, and [iNet Network Scanner](https://inetapp.de/en/inetx.html) shows it under "Bonjour browser" but not under "Network scanner".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not positive this answer will work, but these are the first things I'd try.

To answer your questions:

1) Yes, that configuration should work.

2) You can see it because it is a Bonjour device - just because you can't connect to it doesn't mean that it doesn't exist.

3) Check the settings on the printer. You can either do this on the screen of the printer (assuming it has one) or by opening a web browser and typing the internal IP address into the address bar. Make sure that the printer is configured to get its IP address using DHCP and is not self (manually) assigned.

Comment: How is my computer finding it as a Bonjour device when it doesn't seem to be appearing on the network in any way?

Comment: Turned out the printer was in fact configured with a static IP, and I was able to switch it to DHCP via the hardware control panel.